# Checking if a user is in one of the groups

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery

this is the current script that i found online which checks if a user logged into SharePoint is part of a group. As you can see in the syntax below, it is used to check if the user is part of the devHelpDeskV2 Members group

```
function IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup() {
    var grpName = "devHelpDeskV2 Members";
    var userInGroup;
    var currentContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var currentWeb = currentContext.get_web();
```

My question is, how should i modify or add so that i can check on more groups. For example, Let's say i have 2 more groups, devAccount and devShipping. Will it work if i add them like so?

**Just as an update**, the following is the code that i currently am using on SPO edit form page via Script Editor. The goal was to check if the user was part of a group and disable some fields in edit form so that the user will not be able to change their entry. The part which does the disabling of the fields is the  **if (userInGroup)** part

How should i fit that into the coding that you guys suggest?

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup, "sp.js");
});

function IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup() {
    var grpName = "devHelpDeskV2 Members";
    var userInGroup;
    var currentContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var currentWeb = currentContext.get_web();

    var currentUser = currentContext.get_web().get_currentUser();
    currentContext.load(currentUser);

    var allGroups = currentWeb.get_siteGroups();
    currentContext.load(allGroups);

    var group = allGroups.getByName(grpName);
    currentContext.load(group);

    var groupUsers = group.get_users();
    currentContext.load(groupUsers);

    currentContext.executeQueryAsync(OnSuccess, OnFailure);

    function OnSuccess(sender, args) {

        var groupUserEnumerator = groupUsers.getEnumerator();
        while (groupUserEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var groupUser = groupUserEnumerator.get_current();
            if (groupUser.get_id() == currentUser.get_id()) {
                userInGroup = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (userInGroup) {
            //alert("user exists in the group");
            //do some operation.
            $("input[type=text],textarea").prop("disabled","true").css('background-color','#F6F6F6');

        } else {
            //alert("user doestn't exist in the group");
        }

    }

    function OnFailure(sender, args) {
        //error message.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the REST API below to get all the current user groups, and then check if groups in the "grpName".

**`/_api/web/currentuser/groups?$select=Title`**

The following code for your reference.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $(".sp-peoplepicker-delImage").hide();
    if(IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup()){
        //do some operation.
        $("input[type=text],textarea").prop("disabled","true").css('background-color','#F6F6F6');
    }
});
function IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup(){
    var grpName=["devHelpDeskV2 Members","devAccount","devShipping"];
    var isUserInGroups=false;
    var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/currentuser/groups?$select=Title";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        async:false,
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
            for(var i=0;i<grpName.length;i++){
                for(var j=0;j<data.d.results.length;j++){
                    if(grpName[i]==data.d.results[j].Title){
                        isUserInGroups=true;
                    }
                }
            }                       
        },
        error: function (error) {
            //console.log(JSON.stringify(error));  
        }
    });
    return isUserInGroups;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks LZ, i have updated my question with more information. Need help in placing the IF statement into your code

Comment: I update my code in the reply, add the if statement in the code.

Comment: hope you don't mind asking, i have a code with removed the X from a people picker field. The code that i used is: **$(".sp-peoplepicker-delImage").hide();** Doesn't seem to be working anymore. Everything else does. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Add the code into $(function(){ //add code });, if you want to hide the removed code, we an also use CSS to achieve it.  <style type="text/css">.sp-peoplepicker-delImage{display:none;}</style>

Comment: Hi LZ, i tried adding the code after $(function(){ like your updated example above, didn't seem to work. Where would i add the CSS code? Thanks

Comment: Add the CSS code into script editor web part in edit form page.

Comment: Thank you LZ, initially the plan was to hide the (x) delete image for people picker if the user us part of a group that is specified in the scripe eg devShipping. This way users who are not part of the specified group like admins can freely edit entries in the list. Your method straight out hides the (x) delete image all together which is fine as well. Regards

Comment: do you know if instead of adding individual users into groups i just use the default Sharepoint group Everyone except for External Users, will that work?

Answer (score 1):

may be this code will be helpful.

```
var ConstantGroupName=["Test1"];//decalre groups where you want to check user
$.getJSON(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/currentuser/?$expand=groups&$select=groups/Title").done(function(d){
console.log(d.Groups);
if(d)
{
    if(d.Groups.length>0)
    {

        var groupsName=$.map(d.Groups,function(o){return o.Title});//this will retrun current user group title array;
        var found = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < ConstantGroupName.length; i++) 
        {
            if (groupsName.indexOf(ConstantGroupName[i]) > -1)
                {
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
        }
        console.log(found);
       }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below script to check current logged in users is a group.

```
function checkUserInGroup(groupArray, grpArray) {
 return groupArray.some(function (v) { return grpArray.indexOf(v) != -1; 
 });
}

function getCurrentUserGroup() {   
return jQuery.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/currentuser/?$expand=groups&$select=groups/Title",
    method: "GET",
    async: false,
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" }        
});    
}

function successgetUsers(data) {
var grpArray = ["group1", "group2", "group3", "group4"];

var groupArray = new Array();
jQuery.each(data.d.Groups.results, function (i, result) {
    groupArray.push(result.Title);
});

checkUserInGroup(groupArray, grpArray) ? alert('found user in group') : 
 alert('Not found user in group');  
}

function failgetUsers(){
alert('failed to getCurrentUserGroup ');
}

getCurrentUserGroup().then(successgetUsers, failgetUsers);
```

Comment: Thanks Robert, i have updated my question with more details. I need help / advise in making the code work